# ng build --prod --configuration=production --base-href /folder_name/ --aot not generate unique hash with Angular 6

Tags: angular

```
ng build --prod --configuration=production --base-href 
         /folder_name/ --aot
```

command always generates same hash not unique. We are using Angular 6 and try to create build for prod deployment. Below is my Angular and CLI Version:

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.5
Node: 10.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.8.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.10.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.10.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.10.3
@angular-devkit/core              0.8.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.8.5
@angular/cli                      6.2.5
@ngtools/webpack                  7.0.3
@schematics/angular               0.8.5
@schematics/update                0.8.5
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.19.1
```

Please let me know what's wrong with my configuration.

```
"production": {
    "optimization": true,
    "outputHashing": "all",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "extractCss": true,
    "namedChunks": false,
    "aot": true,
    "extractLicenses": true,
    "vendorChunk": false,
    "buildOptimizer": true,
    "fileReplacements": [{
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }]
}
```

Comment: The hashes should only change if you made changes to the code that resulted in the output differing. (e.g., adding several extra spaces to the end of a source file should not change the output

Comment: Same behavior even if I made any changes in code...

Comment: We have upgrade angular 4.3 to 6.1.10 . Is there any issue regarding this so that we are facing this issue ?

Comment: maybe this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11915) will be helpful for you.

Comment: it means you dont need to use `--aot` flag after using `--prod`. turning on `--prod` automatically turns on `--aot`. so you dont need to pass both flags.

Comment: I noticed that when i made changes in global css it generate new hash however when i made changes in code (.ts) it not generate new hash. 

I think something missing ??

Comment: how much changes you made in code, because as per angular hashes changes per bundle content, not per build. So between two builds, if the content of the bundle did not change, the hash will not change.

Comment: only add console.log('hello'); in code(2 .ts file)

Comment: well, in this case, I am unable to understand what thing you are missing and I am afraid I can't help about this because I ran the same test case like adding console.log in a function in one file and generate the build and the hashes of two files were changed after build.

Comment: what should I do now to resolve this ??